# avformat_open_input function crashing

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

I'm trying to open a file using `avformat_open_input` and it crashes even if the file exists.

```
av_register_all();

AVFormatContext *avFormatContext;

if (avformat_open_input(&avFormatContext, argv[1], NULL, NULL) < 0)
{
    av_log(0, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Wasn't possible opening the file: %s", argv[1]);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: [Did you read the documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.3/group__lavf__decoding.html#ga10a404346c646e4ab58f4ed798baca32)? It clearly says that the `AVFormatContext` is a "pointer to user-supplied `AVFormatContex`t (allocated by `avformat_alloc_context`). May be a pointer to `NULL`, in which case an `AVFormatContext` is allocated by this function and written into `ps`".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must NULL the avFormatContext variable first:

```
av_register_all();

AVFormatContext *avFormatContext = NULL;

if (avformat_open_input(&avFormatContext, argv[1], NULL, NULL) < 0)
{
    av_log(0, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Wasn't possible opening the file: %s", argv[1]);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I solved this with: `avformat_alloc_context`. - I will accept your question anyway, also works. Thanks.